# Resteasy @Path(value = "/") vs @Path(value = "") are they same

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

I am using Resteasy. If I declare a method and use

```
@Path(value = "/") or @Path(value = "")
```

on that method.
Is both of them are same? I mean `http://localhost:8080/test` and `http://localhost:8080/test/` will hit same method.

If yes (which is what my finding is). Then how can I identify the requests `http://localhost:8080/test and http://localhost:8080/test/` and map them to separate functions, I have separate number of get parameters in both the requests.

Comment: Not sure but I would guess no, "/" should go to root ("http://localhost:8080") and "" should go to current directory, same as "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JAX-RS specification (page 17)](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1392985182_0844e1c2927f9d9682d0d0abfee1b750), section 3.7.3 Converting URI Templates to Regular Expressions:

```
4. If the resulting string ends with '/' then remove the final character.
```

Therefore, `@Path(value = "/")` and `@Path(value = "")` will hit the same method, because the trailing `/` on the first `@Path` will be removed.

Accordingly, the requests `http://localhost:8080/test` and `http://localhost:8080/test/` **do not** differ to one another.